# Как узнать положение символа в массиве?

Tags: php

Есть задача узнать положение символа в массиве. Есть некий двумерный массив.

```
$lang=array(
array('a','b','c'),
array('а','б','в'),
array('あ','う','え')
);
```

Мне нужно, чтобы когда я ввожу символ 'う' мне выдавало 2(строка)1(позиция).

> Решение:

```
function search($data){
    global $lang;
    for($x=0; $x<=2; $x++){
        if(array_search($data,$lang[$x])){ #19я строка
            echo $x.array_search($data,$lang[$x]);
        }
    }
}
search("f");
```

Comment: Вы пробовали что-то сделать?

Comment: Пробую щас реализовать это через ф-цию array_search. Думаю тут нужно перебирать через цикл. Мне пока не хватает логики чтобы реализовать. Но сдаватся я не собираюсь.

Comment: Чтобы вас не минусовали, добавьте свои наработки в вопрос.

Comment: Я только набрасываю наработки. Добавлять то нечего пока-что

Comment: @Ezdrael вы всё правильно думаете, осталось сделать. Перебирайте массивы по очереди, в очередном через [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-search.php) ищите символ, если нашли `break` поможет выйти из цикла перебора массивов.

Comment: @Ezdrael, если есть загвоздка в чем-то определенном задавайте вопросы. В вашем случае очень важно чтобы вы учли то, что при возврате array_search() есть разница между 0 и false

Comment: Ну вот, оказывается что почти все решилось, достаточно просто немного посидеть и подумать, а не бежать сразу к дяденькам на ресурсы с вопросами

Comment: Я обновил и дополнил

Comment: Ошибку убрал поставив тем самым в условие цикла правильное к-ство массивов в массиве ($x<=9).

Comment: ну вот. уже лучше. Только не используйте глобальные переменные.... чтоб пройтись по всему массиву используйте `count($array)` ........ также вам написали в комментарии но вы не учли тот факт, что `array_seaech` может вернуть позицию `0`, что в контексте `if` вернет `false`.... а значит если вбить первый символ в любой строке - то ничего не сработает

Comment: Я вот как раз это заметил. Эсли пишу search("a") то ничего не показывает. Как решить ето? Может добавить на нулевой ключ пустые поля?

Comment: Просто надо проверять если `array_search($data,$lang[$x]) !== false` т.е. строго соответствие на булево значение.... а чтобы два раза не писать `array_search` (т.к. это лишний цикл)  при условии и при выводе.... то желательно результат поместить в переменную.... написал это в ответе, чтоб вам было на что взглянуть

Comment: Заметил одну тонкость в вашем коде. Когда  мы берем ключ по адресу 00 то выводит 01 вместо 00. Тоесть оно в цикле накидывает единичку когда мы в условии пишем $key

Comment: Видимо php не может одуплить запись вида `$key = array_search($symbol, $array[$i]) !== false` ...... вынес `$key = array_search($symbol, $array[$i])` из условия чтоб не ругался)

Comment: когда я ввожу символы русской раскладки клавиатуры то их не видит. Может ли быть проблема в кодировке?

Comment: Не должно. что-то где-то написано неправильно. или что-то где-то перетирает или еще что. надо смотреть всё вкупе. проблем с кодировкой не должно быть

Comment: Дело в том что если поставить так array('а','б','в','a','b','c') и ввести 'абвabc' то возвратит ключи букв только латинского алфавита. Тоесть '03:04:05'. Это и заставило думать меня что проблема в кодировке.

Comment: Чует мое сердце, что вы хотите сделать одну вещь, а вопрос написали совсем про другую.. Вопрос про массивы и символы, а у вас строка взялась откуда-то. В общем. Скорее всего надо делать что-то совсем другое, а не то, что вы описали в вопросе

Comment: Немного по другому, да. Но я упростил задачу дабы не обяснять людям полную задачу иначе бы это на долго затянулось. А так в основном все по сути описал правильно и разобрался, остается только етая маленькая проблема с кодировкой.

Comment: Вот как раз нужно излагать задачу, которую пытаетесь решить, а не упрощенную версию того, что, как вам кажется, надо доделать)) Переместить зернышко с одного края стола на другой - это одно, а разгрузить фуру с мешками зерна - совсем другое)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Модер почемуто удаляет сообщения

```
function search($data){
    global $lang;
    for($x=0; $x<=2; $x++){
        if(array_search($data,$lang[$x])){ #19я строка
            echo $x.array_search($data,$lang[$x]);
        }
    }
}
search("f");
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$lang=array(
    array('a','b','c'),
    array('а','б','в'),
    array('あ','う','え')
);

$letter = 'а';

search_in_array($letter, $lang);

function search_in_array ($letter, $array)
{
    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
        foreach ($v as $item => $l) {
            if ($letter == $l) {
                echo 'Row: ' . $k . '<br>';
                echo 'Position: ' . $item . '<br>';
                echo 'Letter: ' . $l . '<br>';
                /*
                  Будет выводить все совпадения, 
                  чтобы получить позицию только первого совпадения
                  необходимо раскомментировать break; ниже
                */
                //break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

или

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$lang=array(
    array('a','b','c'),
    array('а','б','в'),
    array('あ','う','え')
);

$letter = 'c';

search_in_array($letter, $lang);

function search_in_array ($letter, $array)
{
    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {

        if (array_search($letter, $v) !== false) {
            echo 'Row: ' . $k . '<br>';
            echo 'Position: ' . array_search($letter, $v) . '<br>';
            echo 'Letter: ' . $letter . '<br>';

            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: аргументируйте - "array_search() работать не будет"

Comment: array_search() ищет значения в обычном простеньком массиве типо array(1,1,2,1,1), а у вас? у вас вложеный массив => array(array(1,1,1),array(1,1,1,1)) его можно использовать только рядом с foreach или чисто на одном foreach(как и сделал автор)!!

Comment: И автор, добавь после слова echo 'Letter: ' . $l; break 2; мыже ищем один элемент, вдруг создатель темы не знает такой фитчи.

Comment: @ДенисКотляров, Автор написал что решение с array_search работать не будет ), но никто не говорил, что нужно отказаться от внешнего цикла

Comment: Теперь все здорово )

Comment: На самом деле, раз это функция, то надо бы писать `return` и тогда `break` не нужен будет. имхо... и стоит не два раза писать `array_search($letter, $v)` в `if` и `echo`, а один раз вынести в переменную чтоб заюзать) а то получится больше циклов)) ну это я так, просто, занудствую

Answer (score 4):

```
$lang = array(
    array('a','b','c'),
    array('а','б','в'),
    array('あ','う','え')
);

function searchSymbol($array, $symbol) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); ++$i) {        
        $key = array_search($symbol, $array[$i]);       
        if ($key !== false) {                               
            return 'Символ: '.$symbol.'<br/>'.
                   'Строка: '. $i.'<br />'.
                   'Позиция: '. $key;           
        }
    }

    return 'Ниче не найдено, сэр! ¯\_(ツ)_/¯';
}

echo searchSymbol($lang, 'a');
```

Answer (score 0):

решение как вариант

```
$lang=array(
   array('a','b','c'),
   array('а','б','в'),
   array('あ','う','え')
);

$search = 'b';

$lang = array_map(function($e) {
   implode('',$e)
},$lang);    

for($i=0;$i<count($lang);$++) {
  $pos = strpos($lang[$i],$search);
  if($pos !== false) {
     print_f("Строка %s",$i);
     print_f("Позиция %s",$pos);
     print_f("Символ %s",$search);
  } else {
     echo "Not found";
  }
}
```

Comment: ...не фурычит))